# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. - Apache Kafka 3.1

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, slf4j

I am trying to run Apache Kafka from git source but I am getting `multiple SLF4J bindings` warn which leads into a failure when using docker containers.

according to the documentation;

```sh
git clone --depth 1 --branch 3.1 https://github.com/apache/kafka.git

cd kafka

./gradlew clean
./gradlew dependencyUpdates
./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6

export UUID=$(./bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid); ./bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t $UUID -c ./config/kraft/server.properties
```

as a result I get:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/core/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/tools/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/trogdor/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/api/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/transforms/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/runtime/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/file/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/mirror/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/mirror-client/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/json/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/basic-auth-extension/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/core/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/tools/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/trogdor/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/api/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/transforms/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/runtime/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/file/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/mirror/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/mirror-client/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/json/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/kafka/connect/basic-auth-extension/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here is that the `kafka-storage` script is loading the same jar multiple times.

The versions aren't different, so there's no actual problem. The `bin/kafka-run-class` script should be doing proper classpath isolation

You shouldn't need Gradle to run KRaft mode

Comment: Could you provide an example of command to launch a producer or consumer?

Comment: @Cr4zyTun4 The Kafka quickstart documentation should refer to both console producer and consumer scripts

Answer (score 0):

My thought about this issue is that you have to get rid of multiple jar files in your directory: **/home/ubuntu/kafka/***
which is related with SLF4J: **slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar** (currently in your case)

**Note: Leaving this thing just as it is actually doesn't stop you from running Kafka server, but everytime you want to log something related with Kafka, this error will pop out causing big annoyance.**

In my case I deleted all other slf4j folders in kafka, except which are in **/home/ubuntu/kafka/tools/build/** and it solved my problem!